# How to place a negative number in a list

Tags: list, emacs, eval, quote

How can I assign a negative number to a list of numbers?

[I read elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592596/giving-a-symbol-a-negative-value-in-lisp) that you can use `(- number)` to negate a number, but for some reason, this is not working as expected in a list: `'((- 1) 2 3))`.

Comment: This question is weird as stated (i.e. with number literals), because `'(-1 2 3)` is absolutely fine.

Comment: Why do you mean by "assign a number to a list"?  Also "add a negative" doesn't mean very much to me.  Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(- 1)` is an *expression* that *evaluates* to `-1`. Quoting (the `'` in front of your code) prevents the *evaluation* of an *expression*. Therefore:

```
> '((- 1) 2 3)
'((- 1) 2 3)
```

but

```
> (list (- 1) 2 3)
'(-1 2 3)
```

or, if you read up about quasiquoting and you want to show off

```
> `(,(- 1) 2 3)
'(-1 2 3)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I need to look more heavily into `'`, as it seems to be really confusing me.  I had to write multiple functions that each took in a list, and I would pass the lists in as `(function-name '(1 2 3 4))`, and this worked, so I assumed I was creating lists correctly, however, it did not work in the case of the negative, so now I have to use `(function-name (list (- 1) 2 3 4))` only in the case of a negative list.  It is a bit confusing.  At any rate, thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: If that's all there is to it, then, as @phils says, just use `'(-1 2 3 4)`.

Comment: @joe_04_04: I recommend that you update your question with an example function demonstrating the problem.