# QuickBase Pipeline Jinja expression IN not working for negative numbers for a LIST

Tags: list, jinja2

I want to provide a User understandable field to make choices so as to send notifications based on those choices, i.e. (1 Day before, Due Date, 1 Day After, 1 Week After).

The above will get converted to 1, 0 -1, -7 (FollowUp Days) & compared to another calculated field that has the # of days difference (FollowUp Diff) between the Due & current date. All fields are converted to string.

This Jinja expression does not seem to work if there are negative numbers.

I've tried using '| string' after both as well as putting the negative #'s in parenthesis perhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/48437799/how-to-place-a-negative-number-in-a-list.
Also tried {{'-1'}} that did not work.

```
{# Nbr of days from Due Date #}
{% if a.follow_up_diff in a.follow_up_days | list %}
    True
{% endif %}

{# Nbr of days from Due Date #}
{% if a.follow_up_diff | string in a.follow_up_days | string | list %}
    True
{% endif %}
```

So long as the current # of days is before the current date it works but once a negative number such as -1 day after the current date then it fails.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuAYX.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you print the `a.follow_up_days | list`, you will realize Jinja is splitting the string character by character, not by the comma delimiter you expected to.

What you want instead is to use `split()` function.

```
{# Nbr of days from Due Date #}
{% if a.follow_up_diff in a.follow_up_days.split(',') %}
    True
{% endif %}
```